# How to Send Multimedia Message using Image through SMS / MMS cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have bult an application using `cordova 4.3` not `phonegap`. The only way am having a problem is on sending a Multimedia Message that can contain image through SMS / MMS?

I have done some research on the pluign website for cordova but they are only for plain SMS text messaging.

Please any body can help me , if i can create my own MMS plugin or modify cordovas community version if it is possible ?

Comment: you can use Phonegap-MMS-Plugin.

Comment: am using cordova 4.3 not phonegap does it able to work for me?

Comment: yeah there's this plugin: https://github.com/christyrajupaul/Phonegap-MMS-Plugin but it is unstable

Comment: I get the following error when using the Phonegap-MMS-Plugin Uncaught module org.apache.cordova.plugin.sms.Sms already defined

Comment: @Zeeshan may be an already imported library so , try to import only one of them if possible or comment out on of them out of the package